# Linking or Mapping two tables together

Tags: sql

Consider my data as inventory list separated by categories.
When I started I had one table that should have been split into two tables, else in the oldTable the columns in a given row would have been un-related.  I have created two new tables in my database, one for categories and the other for data/items.  Now I am trying to use the oldTable existing data to fill the newTable data/items table so I can learn SQL and not have to manually do it.  The categories table I filled in manually because I could not see how to do it otherwise.

The old table has:

```
tableName (
  id, 
  categoryA, 
  categoryB, 
  categoryC, 
  categoryD, 
  categoryE, 
  categoryF,  
  isPriorityA, 
  isPriorityB, 
  isPriorityC, 
  isPriorityD, 
  isPriorityE, 
  isPriorityE
)
```

The new tables have:

```
Categories (
 cat_id, 
  name
)

dataItem (
  item_id, 
  cat_id, 
  name, 
  priority, 
  description, 
  URL
)
```

How do I force the new dataItem table to require the `cat_id` match one of the values in the `Categories.cat_id` table column?  Perhaps to give an error if a value is added outside of the range?  I believe this may be mapping or linking tables, to thereby make them relationship tables.
How do I copy the tableName data to the dataItem table one column at a time in alphabetical order bringing the name,priority with it and allowing it to auto-increment the `item_id` value?

Comment: Which platform are you using - sql server, mysql, oracle, sqlite
, etc?

Comment: Can you provide us some sample data from the old table, and an example of what you would want to result in the new dataItem table?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a foreign key to limit dataItem.cat_id to values in Categories.cat_Id. Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dataItem ADD FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES Categories(cat_id);
```

Exact syntax may depend on which database you are using. For more info on foreign keys see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp